# Can I use stopwords, case insensitivty and removing punctuation in Elastic search Keyword data type?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Actually, as we know for keyword data type we have to use normalizer, but I am gettting an error to use stopword in normalizer. Is there any other way to add stopwords in normalizer for keyword data type?

[image]

It is working for lowercase but not for stop word.
Can any one help me out?

I am just want track or any sample code...
Or I have to convert keyword data type into text?

Comment: You can use [token filters in normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) to remove stop words. What have you tried with stop words that isn't working (and please as code and not a screenshot of code)?

Comment: PUT custom_mappping_sagar
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer_s": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter":["lowercase", "stop"]
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/573153/xeraa  But in normalizer it doesn't have any option for stopwords, just like in analyzer.